# Error al iniciar ubuntu "Loop login" y se desmonta mi partición /home

Tags: ubuntu

He estado teniendo un problema al iniciar en ubuntu, tengo 2 sistemas instalados (Windows y ubuntu) al iniciar en ubuntu tengo el problema de el loop de inicio de sesión intente con varías soluciones ofrecidas por la comunidad sin resultado alguno. 
Después de un largo tiempo probando soluciones note que mi carpeta \home estaba vacía entonces por recomendación de unos amigos borre la carpeta y volví a montar la partición de \home y logré iniciar al sistema de nuevo.

Ahora cada que inicio en ubuntu debo borrar la carpeta \home y volver a instalar la partición.

Por qué mi home se desmonta y como solucionarlo ?

Debo decir que tengo un disco HDD de un tera (Donde se encuentra \home) y un ssd de 128 (Donde se encuentra la raíz)
Comandos para volver a montar home:

**rm -rf /home/**

**mkdir /home && mount /dev/sda4 /home/**

Comment: Tal y como comentar en algunas publicaciones puede ser que tengas 'file system errors.' Como es un problema muy abstracto puedes poner lo que ya has intentado para facilitar la tarea a otros usuarios [info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803533/home-folder-empty-after-restart). De todas formas te **recomiendo** que muevas la pregunta a la seccion de ubuntu ya que ahi te podran ayudar de verdad , ya que esta web es mas de programacion [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com). Un saludo :)

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el contenido del archivo `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que tú instalación de Linux haya sido alterada por algún archivo/configuración y necesites resetearla.

> sudo fsck /dev/sda1

Con eso vas a ver si tienes algún error en algún sitio y también puedes resetear todas las configuraciones con

> sudo dconf reset -f

De todas maneras, si ya no tienes datos y no te importa reinstalar. Me haría una instalación limpia de 0 nueva y vería si se me vuelve a replicar el error.